# Deserializing an enum gives first / wrong value

Tags: xml, serialization, import, enums

I'm working with a 3rd party XSD and its crappy. However all the enums are not deserializing correctly they are are defaulting to the first value.

Here is a sample of one of the enums

```
public enum LoanIdentifierBase
{
    NotSet,
    AgencyCase,
    InvestorCommitment,
    InvestorContract,
    InvestorLoan,
    InvestorWorkoutCase,
```

and here is the class that uses this enum

```
public class LoanIdentifierEnum : BaseClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("SensitiveIndicator")]
    public bool SensitiveIndicator { set; get; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool SensitiveIndicatorSpecified { set; get; }

    [XmlAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", DataType = "NCName")]
    public string label { set; get; }

    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr { set; get; }


    public LoanIdentifierBase Values { set; get; }
}
```

I have tried several tags and permutations but no matter what I do the values all come back as Not Set.

Here is the import file associate with this

[image]

Comment: The LenderCase value is in the enum its just further down than I listed.

Answer (score 0):

Its a stupid answer but it works

```
public LoanIdentifierBase Values { set; get; }
```

Becomes

```
[XmlText]
public string RealValue { set; get; }

public LoanIdentifierBase Value => (LoanIdentifierBase) Enum.Parse(typeof(LoanIdentifierBase), RealValue);
```

And that allows the value to deserialize into the correct enum value